# Properly initialize a ViewModel and pass it to a Composable - Jetpack compose - Coroutines

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I am building an android app using compose and kotlin. I am a beginner and this is my first app.
I am facing the following issue: 
I have a viewModel which is is initialized using the init{} method. This method retrieves data from a database via coroutines using viewModelScope.launch{}. These coroutines apparently take some time to finish.
In the meantime, the viewModel is passed to a screen composable, at which point it has not yet been properly initialized. My screen therefore does not look the way it should.
**Question**: How do I make sure the init method has finished before the screen composable is composed ?

Here are the pieces of code that I think are relevant.

viewModel init method:

```
class HomeViewModel(
private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager,
private val itemsRepository: ItemsRepository) : ViewModel() {
...//some code
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        dataStoreManager.getSettingsDetailsFromDataStore()
            .collect {
                    data ->
                chosenLanguages = data.boolList
                preferredLanguage = data.preferredLanguage
            }
    }
    viewModelScope.launch {

        Log.d("TAG started", listOfCollections.toString())
        dataStoreManager.getCollectionSetFromDataStore()
            .collect {
                    data ->
                    listOfCollections = data.collectionSet.toMutableList()
                    checkList = mutableStateListOf<Boolean>().apply {
                        repeat(listOfCollections.size) {
                    add(false)
                }
            }

                Log.d("TAG finished", listOfCollections.toString())
            }
    }

    viewModelScope.launch {
        itemsRepository.getAllItemsStream(collectionName)
            .collect { items ->
                _homeListUiState.value = HomeListUiState(items)
            }
    }



}
...// rest of the code
```

The screen composable:

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter", "StateFlowValueCalledInComposition")
    @Composablefun 
HomeScreen(
    navigateToItemEntry: () -> Unit,
    navigateToItemEdit: (Int,String) -> Unit,
    navigateToTableEntry: () -> Unit,
    navigateToSettings: () -> Unit,
    navigateToCollectionEdit: (String) -> Unit,
    navigateToHelp: () -> Unit,
    navigateToPurchase: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {


   ...

    Log.d("TAG In Between", viewModel.listOfCollections.toString())
... //rest of the code
```

And the logs look like this:

```
2023-11-05 11:11:28.809 23754-23754 TAG Started [Main]
2023-11-05 11:11:28.820 23754-23754 TAG In Between  [Main]
2023-11-05 11:11:29.728 23754-23754 TAG finished [Main, r, vb]
```

`[Main, r, vb]` is what it should be before the homescreen is built. the logs should be

```
2023-11-05 11:11:28.809 23754-23754 TAG Started [Main]
2023-11-05 11:11:28.820 23754-23754 TAG finished [Main, r, vb]
2023-11-05 11:11:29.728 23754-23754 TAG In Between [Main, r, vb]
```

I have tried a bunch of things with `delay`, `async`, `await`, `runblocking`, but nothing worked. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Something that I always do is either I add a splash screen so that I load the data first before navigating or another approach is to add a circular progress indicator while loading the data and when finished display the data

Comment: Thank you I will look into these two methods.